# Dask install fails in windows with error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: anaconda, dask

When executing the following command on windows

```
conda install dask
```

The install fails with the following error message:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try upgrading conda and going again, and if still broken, raise an issue with anaconda distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this situation should not happen. It could be that your conda is out of date or that there was some temporary situation with the network or state of the repo server which caused it. I would therefore recommend trying to upgrade conda and trying the process again.

If you find that the error persists, you should certainly raise an issue with the anaconda repo team.